# Using Express, how to implement commonly used wrapper function to deal with errors

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

**Environment:** node.js, Express

I'm attempting to use an error handling pattern based on work done by Valeri Karpov (creator of Mongoose).  He explains the pattern that he uses in this article, [The 80/20 Guide to Express Error Handling](https://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-express-error-handling).

In the simplified server below I can successfully feed errors through to my error handling middleware.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {

    let catStatus = false;

    function answer(X) {
        return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
            if(X) {
                resolve('cat does exist');
            } else {
                reject('whoops, cat does not exist');
            }
        });
    }

    answer(catStatus)
        .then( function(data) {
            res.render('index', { output: data });
        })
        .catch( function(error) {
            next(new Error(error));
        });
});

app.use( function(error, req, res, next) {

    res.render('error', { error });
});

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('listening on port 8080');
});
```

However I'm stuck on how to implement his wrapper pattern with my basic setup. Does the code inside my `'/'` endpoint go inside of his `'*'` endpoint?

If so does anything go inside of his `function wrapAsync(fn)`?  Should I just delete his 2 comment lines and leave it as is?

```
app.get('*', wrapAsync(async function(req, res) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 50));
  // Async error!
  throw new Error('woops');
}));

app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  // Gets called because of `wrapAsync()`
  res.json({ message: error.message });
});

app.listen(3000);

function wrapAsync(fn) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Make sure to `.catch()` any errors and pass them along to the `next()`
    // middleware in the chain, in this case the error handler.
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the `*` endpoint in `app.use()` is just a wildcard saying to route all incoming requests to that code, similar to the way your `/` is working.

But yes, you are understanding correctly. Basically, he is saying that any middleware which makes asynchronous requests should use this `wrapAsync` function. You can remove the comment lines in the `wrapAsync` implementation if you want.

With the `wrapAsync` function, you can pass your own async middleware functionality into this wrapper, and it will make sure to call your async middleware and `.catch()` the promise to call `next`, so that you don't have to worry about that detail when writing code. You can simply throw errors, and then async wrapper will handle the Express requirement of calling `next()` when async code fails.

```
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
    verifyRequestorPermissionsAsync(req.params)
        .catch(err => {
            return next(err);
        });
});
```

With the `wrapAsync` middleware, you will automatically call next with the rejected error (if there is one), so you can clean up the code quite a bit (as well as avoid accidentally forgetting to call next on a rejection).

```
app.use("/", wrapAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
    await verifyRequestorPermissionsAsync(req.params);
}));
```

These two docs / articles will help clear things up a lot, if I am guessing correctly where the confusion is coming from:

- Why do we even care about `next` and passing a value into that function: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html
- What is this wrap function doing, which returns a function that calls your function? https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_hOd+yVxaku

Comment: Thanks Jack your explanation (and 2 links) help a ton!  But now that I can see what's happening with the wrapper I think I might like the low-tech, default way better.  Either way I have to remember to add something to my routes.  In the first I have to remember to use `.catch` and in the second I have to remember to use `wrapAsync`.  `.catch` is more intuitive to someone who doesn't have years of experience using express.

Comment: Agreed, I prefer to pass the errors to next() explicitly as well. I can see why someone might prefer this pattern though.